# Strategy pattern with generics in Java

Tags: java, oop, generics

So I'm trying to create an interface with a generic function to be overrided by a subclass but I can't find a way to do this.

I think a piece of code will be more explicit:

```
interface Agent<A extends Agent<A>> {
    <W extends World> Iterable<Action<A,W>> percepts(W world);
    <W extends World> void takeAction(Action<A,W> action, W world);
}

abstract class StrategistAgent<A extends StrategistAgent<A>> implements Agent<A> {
    abstract public <W extends World> AgentStrategy<A,W> getStrategy();
    abstract public <W extends World> void setStrategy(AgentStrategy<A,W> strategy);

    @Override
    <W extends World> Iterable<Action<A,W>> percepts(W world) {
        return getStrategy().run(this, world);
    }
}

interface AgentStrategy<A extends StrategistAgent<A>, W extends World> {
    Iterable<Action<A,W>> run(A agent, W world);
    void init(A agent, W world);
}
```

error: The method run(A, World) in the type AgentStrategy is not applicable for the arguments (StrategistAgent, W)

but I cannot write :

```
StrategistAgent<A extends StrategistAgent<A>, W extends World>
```

**EDIT:** Ok I followed Mark Peters' advice and removed the setStrategy method. Should be working now..

Comment: Remove the offending type constraint? It seems like you've got a circular dependency in type constraints between Agent and StrategistAgent, you need to break the cycle somehow.

Comment: ok I narrowed down the problem : percepts is ok but it cannot call run which should be correct... replacing Iterable<Action<A,W>> run(A agent, W world); in AgentStrategy by Iterable<Action<A,W>> run(StrategistAgent<A> agent, W world); shows the error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterable<Action<A,World>> to Iterable<Action<A,W>>

Comment: Why does your strategy need to be typed on the specific subclass of agent at all?  It would be helpful if you expanded on what you're actually trying to accomplish since this is absolutely not how generics were designed to be used.

Comment: What do you mean it is not how generics were designed to be used ? I would like to have to possibility to write a strategy for any agent in a world. I believe a strategy instance should be assigned to multiple agents if possible...

Comment: @Tug: Generics were not meant to be used as a hack for self-referential typing, that's what I meant.  It seems a bit like you have a hammer and are now seeing screws as nails.  Where is the "glue" code for this (the code that constructs the concrete agents and populates them with strategies) and how does it benefit from generics?

Comment: I take back some of the strength of my previous statements.  At least to the point where I'll admit I've tried to do stuff like this with generics before :-).  I'm just trying to make sense of your goals and I think I've got it now.

Comment: @Tug generics were primarily designed to remove casting items retrieved from collections – the wildcard incantantions tend to get… well, wild for use cases more complicated than that. (Like the infamous `public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)`.) In your situation, I'd focus on making the type signatures that API clients will need as helpful to said clients possible, and use a limited number of unsafe casts where necessary in internal code instead of wasting hours trying to make the type constraints "perfect".

Comment: @Tug for instance, there's probably no reason for AgentStrategy to constrain A to be a subtype of StrategistAgent – I'm not sure why a strategy would need to call `setStrategy()` on its parent or recursively call `percept()` except to create some very very abstruse code where system components rewire the system at will.

Comment: @Mark I have no goal ;) this is just a little project of mine I started for the google ai challenge. I like to try new stuff and imagine a design I could reuse easily to the point where creating evolutionist strategy for instance should not modify the code too much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right so the problem, as you've probably figured out by now, is that there is nothing saying that where your error occurs, `this` is an instance of `A`.  This is what I was getting at when I was saying that Generics really aren't made for this sort of self-referential typing.

You've got other problems in your design too, though.  For starters the `W` that you accept when you set the strategy might be a completely different class than the `W` that you get when `percept` is called.

So what is your way forward?  Well, again I argue this depends on your glue code, the stuff that creates the agent and strategy and puts them together.

Since that glue code is in all likelihood going to know exactly what type of agent and strategy it's dealing with, you probably don't even *benefit* from making `setStrategy` abstract.  And once it's not abstract, you can just deal with it in each subclass.

Really all you need from your subclasses is a protected method `getStrategy`.  And if you're forcing all your subclasses to provide that, you might as well force them to return the `A` as well:

```
abstract class StrategistAgent<A extends StrategistAgent<A>> implements Agent<A> {
    protected abstract <W extends World> AgentStrategy<A,W> getStrategy();
    protected abstract A getSelf();

    @Override
    public <W extends World> Iterable<Action<A,W>> percepts(W world) {
        return this.<W>getStrategy().run(getSelf(), world);
    }
}
```

So this is one solution.  I'll have to think a bit more to think of a more elegant one though.

Comment: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ206

Comment: Ahh, great find!  Good to know my terminology wasn't completely off-base.